# Has anybody ever tried to use sea animals to pull a ship?

Tags: technology

Given that many land animals throughout history were harnessed to pull land vehicles (horses, bulls, dogs, deer, elephants etc), I wonder whether anyone ever tried or suggested to use sea or river animals such as fish, dolphins or sea birds to pull a ship?

Comment: [related](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/11900/roman-navy-propelled-by-animals-instead-of-human-rowers)

Comment: Very difficult to domesticate sea animals. I'm not aware of any examples. The only animals that I know of that pull ships are mules used to pull canal boats.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can see a dolphin being used to pull a small vessel here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJStZfJ11ZY

Comment: So it is possible. Was it used ever historically for travel/transportation/war?

Comment: Not that I know of. Sails are a lot cheaper to make, give faster top speeds, scale better and don't get tired. Also, they'll never decide to dive all of a sudden.